# Since EasyBCD is no more free as beer, what can I use instead?

Tags: boot, multi-boot, boot-manager, easybcd

Is there an easy-to-use and reliable alternative?

Comment: Thank you guys for closing this late enough for me to get the necessary help! :)))

Comment: We generally consider asking for alternatives to something not constructive but in your case it was a little different :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/Download/Register/1) only costs for a commercial license.

Answer (score 2):

The built in `BCDEDIT` does a great job, as long as you read the help that follows along with it

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but would like to avoid spending another hour between command prompt and MS online help :)